# What does Tete-a-Tete mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I am wondering if `Tete-a-Tete` has a similar meaning as `mutual relation` between two entities such as the following:

- Suicide rate and depression are Tete-a-Tete.

Comment: We would say that they *go hand-in-hand*.

Answer (score 1):

"[tête-à-tête](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tete-a-tete)" is taken from French, and it literally means "head-to-head", better translated to English: "face-to-face".

It is used for the discussion of two persons, when they concentrate their attention to each other (unlike having a casual conversation while each of the persons is concentrated on some other activity). Usually is a private conversation, but not necessarily secret. It can happen in a cafe, where people around may hear what is being discussed.

It is NOT recommended to use it for other purposes or with other similar meanings: side-by-side, together, related, competing, hand-in-hand...

---

> I am wondering if Tete-a-Tete has a similar meaning as mutual relation between two entities such as the following:
>
> - Suicide rate and depression are Tete-a-Tete.

No, it does not have such meaning.

Answer (score -2):

**[tête-à-tête](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tete-a-tete)** - *an informal private conversation between two people, especially friends*

But it can also mean "**side by side**" or "**closely related**".

Comment: So that my sentence in the question is meaningful?

Comment: It's borrowed from French, meaning head-to-head.  It sounds like the quote is about comparing rates of suicide and depression.  Saying they are head-to-head would mean that the rates are very similar.  It's the kind of thing you might say about two horses in a race if they were side-by-side on the track, performing the same.

Comment: @lonesome No, I have only ever heard tête-à-tête used when talking about a private meeting between two people. It does not mean the same as "equivalent" or "of about the same value".

Comment: @fixer1234 While tête-à-tête literally translates as head-to-head, it doesn't mean the same as the English phrase _head-to-head_, which means _two competitors in direct competition_. Also, neither would be used when describing a close-run (e.g. horse, car or running) race, where the phrase _neck-and-neck_ would be used.

Comment: @lonesome tête-à-tête is synonymous with the phrase _one-on-one_.

Comment: *But it can also mean "side by side" or "closely related".* [citation needed] (–1)

Comment: @SteveES But does 'one-on-one' mean that? I've always understood that to mean one-to-one conflict. Or is this a UK / US thing? (I'm in the UK)